# Two-way WeakMap keeping objects alive?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, weakmap, ephemeron

Assume I have two WeakMaps:

```
a2b = new WeakMap<A, B>();
b2a = new WeakMap<B, A>();
```

If I now do:

```
a2b.set(a, b);
b2a.set(b, a);
```

Will this keep both a and b alive or will they be finalized if nobody else is holding on to either a or b?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: I think only the values are held weakly, and the keys are held strongly

Comment: I would guess, that they would both be garbage collected because if nobody else is holding on to `a` or `b` you would not be able to retrieve any of the values since you always need `a` or `b` and the `WeakMap` to retrieve a value. The values can therefore not be used, so why keep them. But that's just my guess, not knowledge. Interesting question though. Hoping to see some JS experts come to rescue :D

Comment: @DanielA.White No, a `WeakMap` is not a `Map` containing `WeakRef`s as values. Nothing is held strongly but the reference from the key to the value.

Answer (score 0):

They will be garbage collected.
[Firefox has about:memory, which allows you to manually trigger garbage collection across pages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5syb.png)

Comment: Can you explain why they will be garbage collected?

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not keep the objects alive.

Liveness is determined by reachability from the gc roots, not from circular reasoning. If nothing else keeps the objects alive, they will get garbage-collected - the cyclic dependency on each other's liveness does not matter.

The `a` object will be kept alive if both `b` and `b2a` are alive.
The `b` object will be kept alive if both `a` and `a2b` are alive.
If both are dead, they won't keep each other alive.